# Kill or kick all clients from a running VNC server without restarting the server

Tags: kill, vnc

I encounter quite often the problem
that I want to kick all connected clients from a running VNC server. 
Even better would be to be able to kick / kill only certain clients. 
With `netstat -tupa | grep 5901` I see that several clients are connected,
but I don't know how to disconnect them.

I'm using the TigerVNC-server.

Comment: I found a workaround: install the package dsniff, where the tool tcpkill lives. Then call tcpkill  -i eth0 port 59230, where the port number is the one which is shown as the foreign address. This will disconnect it the hard way.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to disconnect all clients from a running VNC server (Xvnc) –

1. Login to the server, where your `$DISPLAY` is set correctly
2. `vncconfig -disconnect`.

The VNC server isn't affected; it just closes all of the client connections. 
Now you can open a new VNC client connection, if desired.

Comment: Great answer, kicked about 10 duplicate users and now my session is fast again.

Answer (score 0):

This works as well to kill a bunch of VNCs at once:

```
for VARIABLE in {0..99}; do vncserver -kill :$VARIABLE; done
```

Replace `0..99` with the range you want to kill.

Comment: Hi Juan I believe this ... kill ... is terminating the VNC Server processes; instead of just closing Client connections on a running VNC server.
So the original post, here, wanted the other thing.

Answer (score -1):

`` kill `pidof xtightvnc` ``  
I use this option to kill VNC server.

Comment: This kills the server. The user wants to disconnect clients without killing the server.